# External Monitor - Mouse and windows goes out of bounds

Tags: windows-7, display

I have two monitors (my laptop and an external monitor - a flatron M2780D). I'm running Windows 7.

On the flatron, if I maximize a window (such as Firefox), the window goes out of the bounds of the monitor, and I can't really see the outer edges of the window (such as in Firefox, I can't see the buttons to exit, minimize, maximize).

How do I fix this? How do I specify the boundary of my monitor because for some reason it's going out of bounds.

Comment: What are the resolutions of the two monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times this can happen when the monitor itself needs to be calibrated to the dimensions you are using. - you can usually do this from the menu button on the monitor.

-or-

You may be using a resolution not properly suited for the monitor. This can happen a lot in windows when you use the Mirror function, and one monitor is forced to fit the constraints of the other monitor.

-Lastly-

It may depend on whether you are using HDMI or DVI, and how your video card handles both.